# Getting confused with pointers

Tags: c++

I trying to reproduce the **Bridge pattern** from Java book, but getting stuck with pointers dilemma cause I'm novice. I threw away includes and part the of implementation, because it's just **printf**'s over there:

```
// main.cpp
int main () {
    DrawApi *rc = new RedCircle();
    Circle redCircle = new Circle(rc);
    redCircle.draw();
}

// DrawApi.h
class DrawApi
{
public:
    virtual void drawCircle() = 0;
};

// Shape.h
class DrawApi;
class Shape
{
protected:
    DrawApi *drawApi;
public:
    Shape(DrawApi *mDrawApi) : drawApi(mDrawApi) {}
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};

// Circle.h
class Circle : public Shape {
public:
    Circle(DrawApi *mDrawApi) : Shape(mDrawApi) {}
    void draw();
};
```

After compile and run a get an error:

```
$ g++-5 -std=c++14 -g main.cpp RedCircle.cpp Circle.cpp && ./a.out && rm a.out
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:7:46: error: conversion from ‘Circle*’ to non-scalar type ‘Circle’ requested
     Circle redCircle = new Circle(rc);
```

Shape ctor is waiting for pointer to DrawApi but seems gets an object. I thought I declared rc variable as pointer to DrawApi.

Comment: `DrawApi *rc = new RedCircle();`? Did you mean `DrawApi *rc = new DrawApi();`?

Comment: `Circle redCircle = new Circle(rc);` should at least be `Circle* redCircle = new Circle(rc);` (as the compiler tells you) - and `redCircle.draw();` would then be `redCircle->draw();`. But I'm unsure why you would want to do this using pointers and `new` anyway.

Comment: and i  would also add `redCircle.draw();` should be `redCircle->draw();`

Comment: Also every `new` needs a corresponding `delete` otherwise you get memory leaks

Comment: Thank guys, especially UnholySheep! This works: Circle *redCircle = new Circle(rc); redCircle->draw();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Circle redCircle = new Circle(rc);
```

If you want to initialise (copy construct) a `Circle` from `Circle *`, you need a constructor, say `Circle(Circle *)`.

---

I guess that, in fact, you just want to initialise a `Circle` from `rc`. Since `rc` is `DrawApi *`, and `Circle` has a constructor which takes `DrawApi *` as argument, a.k.a `Circle(DrawApi *mDrawApi)`. You can simply write:

```
Circle redCircle(rc);
redCircle.draw();
```

If I was wrong, then maybe:

```
Circle *redCircle = new Circle(rc);
redCircle->draw();
```

I prefer the first version for two reasons:

- they are all calling to Circle's draw, not it's base's.
- `DrawApi` has a virtual member function too, and you have already
  conducted a Derived-to-Base conversion.

---

BTW, your program has some serious memory management issues. Having them solved before go any further will be a good choice. (Smart pointer will help you a lot)

There are subtle differences between `Type obj(x)` and `Type obj = x`.

Comment: I think you like to confuse beginners. :D I'd just use `Circle *redCircle = new Circle(rc);` or better just `Circle redCircle(rc);`.

Comment: Thank you, it works just fine. I don't fully understand the construction Circle redCircle(rc); but it works.